# Encrypting data on both iOS and Android without external dependencies (can I use AES-CBC?)

Tags: aes

I am trying to achieve AWS KMS envelope encryption on both iOS and Android. From the KMS API I get a 256 bit data key in both plaintext and encrypted forms (encrypted by a master key held only on KMS HSMs).

Right now, I am using iOS CommonCrypto and Android's built-in Cryptography library to encrypt sensitive data fields with AES-256-CBC.

This data is then sent over TLS to the server. Eventually, the events containing the encrypted fields are read out into into a secure ETL process where the fields are decrypted for analysis.

The reason I am encrypting on-device is so that the events may flow through existing data analytics infrastructure that isn't built to handle sensitive data. I want to do this without including additional dependencies to my client-side code.

Is CBC an appropriate choice for this? It is unclear to me if I need GCM for this. I can't find a good way to implement AES-GCM on any version of iOS except the latest one, v13.

Am I missing a more obvious design here to meet my needs?

Comment: realted : [Use a AWS KMS AES-GCM key with AES-CBC algorithm from iOS CommonCrypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/74551/use-a-aws-kms-aes-gcm-key-with-aes-cbc-algorithm-from-ios-commoncrypto)

Comment: **You should always use an _authenticated cipher_ like AES-GCM or crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305 and never an _unauthenticated cipher_ like AES-CBC** unless you have a particular reason to use an unauthenticated cipher in an unusual application.  [More details](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/57648) on the difference between the security contracts of these two beasts.  What cryptography might available to you in your circumstances is a programming question beyond the scope of this site, though.

Comment: Thanks @SqueamishOssifrage that post is great. I don't think my use-case necessarily needs authentication/anti-forgery but I'm not sure. Giving that, and the existence of things like padding oracle attacks, it looks like I should use GCM even though it substantially complicates implementation.

Comment: If you're not sure, you should assume you need an authenticated cipher.  Neglecting authentication can lead you to inadvertently leak secrets—this has happened in real-world protocols, like OpenPGP and S/MIME with [EFAIL](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59241).

Comment: AES-GCM is not the only authenticated cipher, of course.  If you have a NaCl binding, there's crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305.  In a pinch, as long as you're careful about it, AES256-CTR/HMAC-SHA256 in encrypt-then-MAC composition serves too.  Just make sure to record some known-answer test vectors that you verify on startup.  That said, if whatever library you're relying on has only AES-CBC and no authenticated ciphers, that's evidence that it's a bad library you should maybe reconsider using.